# How to extract type of recursively nested children properties in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to model a recursive tree relationship of nodes of two types: text nodes and element nodes (like the DOM). Text nodes are leaves in the tree, and element nodes can contain other element nodes or text nodes.

```
type Text = {
    text: string
}

type Element = {
    children: Node[]
}

type Node = Element | Text
```

Consider these nodes:

```
type A = {
    children: Text[]
}

type B = {
    children: A[]
}

type C = {
    children: B[]
}
```

Given a specific `Node`, I'd like to write a utility type that will return the union of its potential descendants (deep).

Writing the utility for just the children (shallow) is straightforward:

```
type ChildOf<N extends Node> = 
    N extends Element
        ? N['children'][number]
        : never

ChildOf<A> // Text
ChildOf<B> // A
ChildOf<C> // B
ChildOf<Text> // never
```

But how would you write a recursive utility to get all of the deep descendants and not just the shallow children?

```
type DescendantOf<N extends Node> = ???

DescendantOf<A> // Text
DescendantOf<B> // A | Text
DescendantOf<C> // A | B | Text
DescendantOf<Text> // never
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just create a union of `ChildOf<N>` and a recursive call of `DescendantOf` inside a conditional type that serves as recursion anchor ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEEBNIU00CuA7WAnAzgYwPapqAF21ABUYAPAgGlAFEAbGAWxiWtAEMVQA5bWUOgCWSTPgIALGOnwc8oAOb1sAIw71CATwAO0gFAEd+MpQD6oALygA3ntD3CFAgC5BBVCIV6AvnoNG6RhY2cytbB1BMCSF6SDwkVz5YUwBtAF0fP0NdXn4YUMDmVgJzAB9SJ1MsgPBLGzsHKJi41lcTEvTM-xyAITrwxujY+NdwTt9u-ABhfob7JuHW0B7x6pypocgAeQAzAB4eUCdWSHRc5IA+OrneI8oTs4YikJuIgH5eFIByBZakL7SKSQCCYKhgqAyEQiriQMAAbuC1vgACLSMQoLgEXYHK5WQ7HFBnJL5UAfDbNbE8K7lVFYE6Y7Hk2KUi5XGHw8EAbiRoFgdIxbFqVlp6MgDP24CuIAqlEmvLR9LYfWFCoFWP2PSlYFq5Xacr5osxMxV-LFbEZWogoHKfV1Tn1qrNBHadRFivVe3apktsIRqCAA)):

```
type DescendantOf<N> = N extends Node ? ChildOf<N> | DescendantOf<ChildOf<N>> : never;

type descendantA = DescendantOf<A> // Text
type descendantB = DescendantOf<B> // A | Text
type descendantC = DescendantOf<C> // A | B | Text
type descendantText = DescendantOf<Text> // never
```

The docs for recursive conditional types can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types).

**Edit:** Version without `ChildOf<N>` ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEEBNIU00CuA7WAnAzgYwPapqAF21ABUYAPAgGlAFEAbGAWxiWtAEMVQA5bWUOgCWSTPgIALGOnwc8oAOb1sAIw71CATwAO0gFAEd+MpQD6oALygA3ntD3CFAgC5BBVCIV6AvnoNG6RhY2cytbB1BMCSF6SDwkVz5YUwBtAF0fP0NdXn4YUMDmVgJzAB9SJ1MsgPBLGzsHKJi41lcTEvTM-xyAITrwxujY+NdwTt9u-ABhfob7JuHW0B7x6pykmBIjdAAeEgA+OtpKVA5MAj2aDdS0-ZSkBCYVGFQ0gG5J0AARaTEULgIAHkAGY7HigJysSDoXLJQ5WcGQlAw6wLFoJUAiYEvUjeUAAflhm22e0O5R+WChAJBYLyW10uwOh1cSBgADcXh9PrBKf82LUrBS-pBqaDwIcQBVKNzflS2H1BbK+UDQT0JWBauV2jLeSK2DNFbrRTspuqIKByn0tU4dcKAe06kK5Sq9pUzayOaggA)):

```
type NodeTypes<T> = Extract<T, Node[]>[number];
type DescendantOf<N extends Node> = N extends {children: infer T} ? NodeTypes<T> | DescendantOf<NodeTypes<T>> : never;

type descendantA = DescendantOf<A> // Text
type descendantB = DescendantOf<B> // A | Text
type descendantC = DescendantOf<C> // A | B | Text
type descendantText = DescendantOf<Text> // never
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!! I coulda sworn I tried something similar but it didn't work. Turns out I was accidentally on an older version of TypeScript and I think this was somewhat newly supported. (In case anyone else makes this mistake in the future!)